# Put a filter on DataView by time

Tags: .net, ado.net

How to filter DataView/DataTable by time? I have a table with datetime column inside and I need to filter by the time that is inside that datetime value. In native SQL it's not so hard but in ADO.NET Expressions it makes a dificulity for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the filter to ignore the date component of the DateTime altogether, then I don't think this is possible by using the filter expression.

However, if filtering by both date and time suits your needs, then you could do something like this :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("t1");
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("DT", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 14, 56, 27, 123)});

DateTime startDT =  new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 14, 56, 27, 123);
DateTime endDT = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 14, 56, 28, 123);

string filter = string.Format(
"DT >= '{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff}' AND DT <= '{1:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff}'",
startDT, endDT);

DataView dv = new DataView(dt, filter, null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

MessageBox.Show("Num Rows selected : " + dv.Count.ToString());
```

Note the use of the ISO date/time format : "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff"
in the filter.

Comment: But I have to use the date that is in the dataset (DT in your example) and I need its <date> part only and filter by its <time> part. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible via Expressions.